# Not getting any data is the last select ok?

Tags: sql, db2-400

This is a db2 query but like SQL Server. I am expecting data here that will 
have all rows where there is no freight credit row (`FRTCRDM`)

This is orders data. All orders sb multi rows based on each item sold gets a row:

```
Order#    Item        qty    Price etc
123        Widget1     1      10.00
123        Widget2     2      20.00
123        FRTWDG      1      5.00
123        FRTCRDM     1      2.00
```

So here, we have a shipping discount of 2.00. What I want is, all records where there was no `FRTCRDM`, no shipping discount.  So we would not want the above example. We would want it if the last row was missing.

```
CREATE VIEW ralib.shpfrtn AS
    SELECT T01.IDORD#, T01.IDDOCD, T01.IDPRT#, 
           T01.IDSFX#, T01.IDSHP#, T01.IDNTU$, T01.IDENT# ,
           (T01.IDNTU$ * T01.IDSHP# ) AS LINTOT, 
           T02.IARCC3, T02.IAPRLC , T01.IDORDT, T01.IDHCD3 
    FROM ASTDTA.OEINDLID T01
      INNER JOIN ASTDTA.ICPRTMIA T02 ON T01.IDPRT# = T02.IAPRT# 
    WHERE t01.iddocd > 20131231
      AND t01.IDHCD3 = 'MDL'    
      AND t01.idord# NOT IN (SELECT t01.idord# FROM astdta.oeindlid b
                             WHERE idprt# = 'FRTCRDM')
```

Comment: You can ignore my edit, jarlh did it and then some

Comment: I think you need select b.idord# instead of t01.idord# in your last subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably the `SELECT t01.idord#`, it results in a correlated subquery (in fact it's `idord# not in (idord#)`which is always wrong), change it to `SELECT idord#`:

```
SELECT T01.IDORD#, T01.IDDOCD, T01.IDPRT#, 
       T01.IDSFX#, T01.IDSHP#, T01.IDNTU$, T01.IDENT# ,
       (T01.IDNTU$ * T01.IDSHP# ) AS LINTOT, 
       T02.IARCC3, T02.IAPRLC , T01.IDORDT, T01.IDHCD3 
FROM ASTDTA.OEINDLID T01
  INNER JOIN ASTDTA.ICPRTMIA T02 ON T01.IDPRT# = T02.IAPRT# 
WHERE t01.iddocd > 20131231
  AND t01.IDHCD3 = 'MDL'    
  AND t01.idord# NOT IN (SELECT idord# FROM astdta.oeindlid b
                         WHERE idprt# = 'FRTCRDM')
```

Or change it to a correct correlated subquery using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT T01.IDORD#, T01.IDDOCD, T01.IDPRT#, 
       T01.IDSFX#, T01.IDSHP#, T01.IDNTU$, T01.IDENT# ,
       (T01.IDNTU$ * T01.IDSHP# ) AS LINTOT, 
       T02.IARCC3, T02.IAPRLC , T01.IDORDT, T01.IDHCD3 
FROM ASTDTA.OEINDLID T01
  INNER JOIN ASTDTA.ICPRTMIA T02 ON T01.IDPRT# = T02.IAPRT# 
WHERE t01.iddocd > 20131231
  AND t01.IDHCD3 = 'MDL'    
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM astdta.oeindlid b
     WHERE idprt# = 'FRTCRDM'
       AND t01.idord# = b.idord#)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the last clause in the `where` you need to remove the table prefix from the subquery:

```
NOT IN (SELECT idord# FROM astdta.oeindlid WHERE idprt# = 'FRTCRDM')
```

Right now you are referring to the id of the outer table `t01` and the `not in` will not work as intended.